# lexical analysis for alphabetic in java

Tags: java

this code analyse digits and operators only i need it to analyse alphabetic only and put invalid for other things what should i do in details i got this code from tutorial site and modified it but no result.

```
     package lexical;

     public class Tokenizer {


int pos;
char[] expression;

Tokenizer(String expression) {
    this.expression = expression.toCharArray();
    this.pos = 0;
}

enum Type { OPERATOR, LITTER, UNKNOWN }

class Lexeme {
    String type, token;
    Lexeme(String type, String token) {
        this.type = type;
        this.token = token;
    }
}

Lexeme getNextToken() {
    StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();
    boolean endOfToken = false;
    Type type = Type.UNKNOWN;
    while (!endOfToken && hasMoreTokens()) {
        while(expression[pos] == ' ' && hasMoreTokens())
            pos++;
        switch (expression[pos]) {
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
                if(type != Type.LITTER) {
                    type = Type.OPERATOR;
                    token.append(expression[pos]);
                    pos++;
                }
                endOfToken = true;
                break;
            case ' ':
                endOfToken = true;
                pos++;
                break;
            default:
                if(Character.isDigit(expression[pos]) || expression[pos] == '.') {
                    token.append(expression[pos]);
                    type = Type.LITTER;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Systax error at position: " + pos);
                }
                pos++;
                break;
        }
    }
    return new Lexeme(type.name().toLowerCase(), token.toString());
}

boolean hasMoreTokens() {
    return pos < expression.length;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String expression = "54+18+5";
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer(expression);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        Lexeme nextToken = tokenizer.getNextToken();
        System.out.print("Type: " + nextToken.type + "\tLexeme: " + nextToken.token + "\n");
    }
}


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This section here is where it is looking for a number and 
gives an error for a non-digit or non-period character.

```
if(Character.isDigit(expression[pos]) || expression[pos] == '.') {
     token.append(expression[pos]);
     type = Type.LITTER;
} else {
     System.out.println("Systax error at position: " + pos);
}
```

Strings can hold anything normallly so you would just eliminate the if statement and do

```
default:
    token.append(expression[pos]);
```

However, if you want to limit the characters in your string, then modify the if condition to check for the characters you want. Instead of:

```
if(Character.isDigit(expression[pos]) || expression[pos] == '.') {
```

Change it to only accept the characters you feel are valid in a string. For example

```
if (Character.isAlphabetic(expression[pos]) || expression[pos] == "-") {
```

You may also want a new identifier instead of

```
type = Type.LITTER;
```

Comment: i am trying since you post your answer but nothing
can you please post all code that check all alphabetic and anything is invalid
thanks in advance

Comment: What characters are alphabetic - just A-Z, a-z ??

Comment: characters are alphabetic a-z

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want to handle "A12" or anything that is part alpha and part numeric. This code will return "A" for "A12"

```
package lexical;

public class Tokenizer {

    int pos;
    char[] expression;

    Tokenizer(String expression) {
        this.expression = expression.toCharArray();
        this.pos = 0;
    }

    enum Type {

        OPERATOR, ALPHA, UNKNOWN, LITTER, ERROR
    }

    class Lexeme {

        String type, token;

        Lexeme(String type, String token) {
            this.type = type;
            this.token = token;
        }
    }

     Lexeme getNextToken() {
        StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();
        boolean endOfToken = false;
        Type type = Type.UNKNOWN;
        // skip whitespace
        while (expression[pos] == ' ' && hasMoreTokens()) {
            pos++;
        } 

        while (!endOfToken && hasMoreTokens()) {

            switch (expression[pos]) {
                case ' ':
                {
                    endOfToken = true;
                    pos++;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    if (Character.isAlphabetic(expression[pos])) {                     
                        token.append(expression[pos]);
                        type = Type.ALPHA;                      
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Systax error at position: " + pos);
                    }
                    pos++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return new Lexeme(type.name().toLowerCase(), token.toString());
    }

    boolean hasMoreTokens() {
        return pos < expression.length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        expression = "Hello World";
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer(expression);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            Lexeme nextToken = tokenizer.getNextToken();
            System.out.print("Type: " + nextToken.type + "\tLexeme: " + nextToken.token + "\n");
        }        
        expression = "123 ABC A12";
        tokenizer = new Tokenizer(expression);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            Lexeme nextToken = tokenizer.getNextToken();
            System.out.print("Type: " + nextToken.type + "\tLexeme: " + nextToken.token + "\n");
        }        
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Type: alpha Lexeme: Hello
Type: alpha Lexeme: World
Systax error at position: 0
Systax error at position: 1
Systax error at position: 2
Type: unknown   Lexeme: 
Type: alpha Lexeme: ABC
Systax error at position: 9
Systax error at position: 10
Type: alpha Lexeme: A
```